# Loading static assets in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, semantic-ui

What is the correct approach to loading static files.  I'm trying to use Semantic UI. I have followed the basic steps here: http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html. I have Node installed, NPM installed, ran the gulp process and built the files. I have also required the files like this:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css')
script(src='semantic/dist/semantic.min.js')
```

My project structure is this:

```
server.js

views/  
  index.jade

semantic/  
  dist/
    semantic.min.css
    semantic.min.js
```

I have checked in the browser and there is no console error but those files aren't listed as a resource. I have checked the server logs and there's no error.

The only thing I can think of, is that I need to set up a public directory to serve static files like:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

**Edit**
I have attempted to do this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

And have moved the files into the public directory. It loads because I can navigate to them in the browser but they aren't being applied.

Is there anyway to require them from the semantic folder?  I like them to be built and required from the same space.

**Edit**

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/semantic.min.css">
      <script src="js/semantic.min.js"></script>
    </title>
    <body>
      <button class="ui button"> Follow</button>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Serverjs:

```
var express    = require('express'),
    ejs        = require('ejs'),
    path       = require('path'),
    app        = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './views');


app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  res.render('index');
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Node is listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line in your app.js file.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

Then create a folder named public in the project root directory and move the css and js files to this folder. A better  way of organising things would be to 
create folders named css and javascript inside the public directory and then place css and js files in these folders.

Then in your template file, include these by adding :

```
link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='css/semantic.min.css')
script(src='javascript/semantic.min.js')
```

Comment: Now it will recognize the file (only by typing it in in the URL) but none of the js or css code will effect the markup.

Comment: How can a js/css file be loaded and then have their effects not take place?

Comment: Remove this part and give it a try  ````type='text/css'````

Comment: I removed it and still no dice.  Is there something I need to do in the route?  Does express require something in the header?

Comment: If you are able to access the css and js files through url, then probably there is some issue with your markup.

Comment: I can only access files when I am in root path e.g. `localhost/subroute` when I navigate to `localhost/subroute/sub-subroute` the assets won't load. Can you add to your answer the solution for this? this way your answer will be more complete.